# Read data from file (not JSON) and convert to objects

Tags: swift

I am trying to read from the content of a file and convert to objects. The content is an array of dictionaries but not JSON(keys are not wrapped in quotes).
The content is like below

```
[ {
    id: 13,
    start: "2018-01-12",
    end: "2018-02-16",
    name: "Fourth item with a super long name"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    start: "2018-02-01",
    end: "2018-02-02",
    name: "Fifth item with a super long name"
  }
]
```

I want to be able to read it and make an array of objects structured like this:

```
struct TimelineItem: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var start: String
    var end: String
    var name: String
}
```

Codable way is preferred but not required.

I have tried Google but got no luck.

Comment: You could write a lot of custom code to process your proprietary, not-quite-JSON data file, or you could make your life a lot simpler and make your not-quite-JSON file into an actual JSON file and write very little code.

Comment: Can't you just turn that file into a JSON?

Comment: I’ll ask the obvious question: Why not just make the file be some standard format (such as JSON) instead of inventing your own format? Seems like a lot of unnecessary work just so you can ditch a few quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to quickly convert the file to JSON?

Comment: Regex, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the not-json string to a json string:

```
let notjson = """
[
{
    id: 13,
    start: "2018-01-12",
    end: "2018-02-16",
    name: "Fourth item with a super long name"
},
{
    id: 14,
    start: "2018-02-01",
    end: "2018-02-02",
    name: "Fifth item with a super long name"
}
]
"""

let pattern = "(\n\\s*)([a-z]*)(:)"
let repl = "$1\"$2\"$3"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let json = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: notjson, options: [], 
    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: notjson.utf16.count), withTemplate: repl)
```

Okay, so now we've reduced it to a previously solved problem, as we say in mathematics. We have json, so we can just decode it:

```
struct Thing : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let start : String
    let end : String
    let name : String
}
let things = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Thing].self, from:json.data(using: .utf8)!)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above you asked if there's a way to convert your text to JSON, so that you could use Codable with it.

Here's a fragile way to do that. If the non-JSON file is a static file bundled with your app, then this shouldn't be a problem. If you're getting this data from some web service, then do not use this.

Read your file into a variable. (Here, I'll manually state it.)

```
let string = """
[
    {
        id: 13,
        start: "2018-01-12",
        end: "2018-02-16",
        name: "Fourth item with a super long name"
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        start: "2018-02-01",
        end: "2018-02-02",
        name: "Fifth item with a super long name"
    }
]
"""
```

Regex replace spaces followed by words and a colon (eg: `id:`) and wrap them in quotes.

```
let json = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+(\\w+): ", with: "\"$1\": ", options: [.regularExpression])
```

This will output the following string:

```
[
    {
        "id": 13,
        "start": "2018-01-12",
        "end": "2018-02-16",
        "name": "Fourth item with a super long name"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "start": "2018-02-01",
        "end": "2018-02-02",
        "name": "Fifth item with a super long name"
    }
]
```

You should then be able to decode the string as JSON using codable.